# Accessing a seemingly public property through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, internal, propertyinfo, bindingflags

Good day all,

I am struggling to determine what's the issue with an attempt to access a public property on a class.

My need is very basic. I have a public class that's correctly instanced in my routine, and I know, thanks to reflector, that this class has a property that I need to reference.

Problem is, the property is defined as thus:

```
public Vector3 root {
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), WrapperlessIcall] get;
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), WrapperlessIcall] set;
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that all my attempts at getting the property simply fail.
I've instanced the Type, and tried with all possible combinations of binding flags

```
Type vtype = myobj.getType()
PropertyInfo[] vproperties;
vproperties = vtype.GetProperties();//(BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
for (int vpropertycounter =0 ; vpropertycounter < vproperties.Length ; vpropertycounter++) {
    Console.write( varbodyproperties[varpropertycounter].Name); <= 'root' never appears in this list
}
```

My suspicion and doubt revolves around the fact that the root property might not be 'visibile' because its getter and setter are 'wrapperless' and 'internal'.
Sadly I don't know if this can be overcome or not.

I would like to know if this property can by all means be accessed, and possibly how to do it.

All feedback is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: addressing the property directly, as in "myobj.root" generates a compiler error for unknown property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods with `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` are usually internal framework methods. You cannot call them directly or via reflection (which is more or less the same thing).

It depends on the library, I found something like this within the Word API where it internally uses VB. To access variant Properties you'll have to call a setter method for example

```
 Property = "" <- doesn't work
 set_Property("") <- works
```

Depends on the API you are trying to access I guess, if those successors are implemented

Apart from that, maybe read the [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx)

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, I realized that I could actually call the setter and getter, which led me to understand that I was using the wrong type for the reflection iteration!